# In CL programming, How to read last record of physical file member

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

I want to read last record of physical file member.

Comment: In RPG this would be `SETLL *END`. Does it make sense to write it in RPG rather than CL?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an override to do this, but you can't read backwards in the file using CL, so what's the point? Probably better to use RPG.

But, you can position a file in CLP using:

```
OVRDBF FILE(file name) POSITION(*NONE | *START | *END | etc.)
```

You can prompt the command to find other positions. The ones I left out have to do with positioning by relative record number or by key.